# Dynamically invoking an XQuery in eXist-db as in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, exist-db

In MarkLogic, we use `xdmp:invoke` function to dynamically execute an XQuery and pass in some parameters. Is there an equivalent in eXist-db, and if yes, please could you provide on example?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to do this in eXist, depending on what you are trying to achieve one way may be better than another.

1) Evaluating an external query:

```
util:eval(util:base64-decode(util:binary-doc("/db/other.xqy") cast as xs:string))
```

2) Dynamically importing an external module into the context:

```
util:import-module("http://my-other-module-ns", "other", "/db/other.xqy"),
util:eval("other:some-function('hello')")
```

**UPDATE**

Important addition from [XQuery wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Dynamic_Module_Loading):

> Because the namespace is declared dynamically, the imported functions
>   have to be invoked using util:eval.

Comment: I'd just add that one of the variants of `util:eval()` (from the first approach here) does allow you to pass it external variables.  See [the function documentation for this function](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/util#eval.3).